# changing JQgrid column name dynamically

Tags: jqgrid

I just need to rename JQgrid column dynamically as per user selection from a list of options. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [jqGrid Documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options), `colNames` cannot be changed after the grid is created.

However, you might be able to simulate a column name change by using several columns. Then you can hide all of them except a single one which will be shown to the user. When the user selects another, just swap in the selected column. For example, if valid columns are [A, B, C, D] you might start by only showing A. Then if the user chooses C, hide A and show C. The main disadvantage to this approach is that you will need to copy the same data to many columns, however.

**Update**

Per Galichev's answer, you can use the [setLabel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method to rename a column header.

Answer (score 16):

You can use this syntax:

```
jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid('setLabel', 0, 'NewLabel');
```

This will change first column name to NewLabel in your grid with id=grid1.

Answer (score 11):

The latest version of jqGrid (4.1+ - possibly earlier) no longer appears to support the column index based setLabel approach described by Galichev, a columnName based approach is provided instead:

```
jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid('setLabel', 'columnName', 'NewLabel');
```

See the [jqGrid Methods wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) for more information.

I've left the previous answer unedited as this approach may be valid in versions prior to 4.1.

Answer (score 2):

**setLabel : ** colname the name of the column (this parameter can be a number (the index of the column) beginning from 0

However the index param does not work with version 4.1 and above.

### Jqgrid uptop version 4.0

```
 $(tableId).jqgrid("setLabel", 0, "BBBBB");
```

### Jqgrid version 4.1 and above

Try using these

```
  $(tableId).setLabel("ColumnName", "AAAAA");
```

or

```
  $(tableId).jqgrid("setLabel", "ColumnName", "BBBBB");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JQGrid1.Columns.FromDataField(ColumnName).HeaderText = ColumnName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave my column name a div

```
'<div id="DateDivId">Date</div>'
```

Then I just changed it the normal way, getElementById, change contents.