# How to change a row's particular cell value in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I want to change a particular rows's cell value, I have the row Id. and I have tried using the following. But it doesnt work.

```
$("#my-jqgrid-table").jqGrid('setCell',rowId,'Currency', '12321');
```

I am using `loadonce: true`

Please can someone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: You need post more details about the grid which you use. The *full* definition of `'Currency'` column in `colModel` is really required. Moreover it's important to know *when* (in which context) you call `setCell`. Is the sell which you need to modify is in editing mode?

Comment: @All - If you don't have the **rowID** and need to know how to get it, [consider this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47330980/1016343).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use `getRowData` and `setRowData` methods to achieve this (they are working directly with *data array*):

```
var rowData = $('#my-jqgrid-table').jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);
rowData.Currency = '12321';
$('#my-jqgrid-table').jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, rowData);
```

Comment: Not sure which version this became available (I'm using `jqGrid-4.5.2`) but `$("#...").getRowData(id)` and `$("#...").setRowData(id, rowData)` work as well.

Comment: @notfed The fact is that the two methods you have mentioned are from the old API. The desine guidelines for any jQuery plugin are to expose just one method and make others available as a string parameter (jQuery UI widget methods work in the same way)

Comment: I don't know  why this user accept another answer....:) because this is standard solution in jqgrid

Comment: @tpeczek it is not working for me. I am using free jqgrid 4.14 version

Comment: @shv22 I can't repro any issue, can you share some more details (via email or something)

Comment: @tpeczek thanks for concern but I posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164231/can-i-update-an-image-in-jqgrid-cell/44177318?noredirect=1#comment75375176_44177318  and Oleg helped to get it.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the correct way according to the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) :-

```
$("#my-jqgrid-table").jqGrid("setCell", rowid, "Currency", "New value");
```

Check that all variables are correct as what you did seems correct.  loadOnce has no impact, you must have a mistake elsewhere.

- Are you sure the row name is Currency (not the index)
- Check the variable rowId, should it be rowid or rowID

Comment: This worked well in my case: I didn't want the change to trigger the format function, as `setRowData` does. Also, check this Oleg's answer if you want to change local data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9145342/1863970

Answer (score -4):

Thanks all for your effort, with help of a friend at work I managed to get this working with some jquery.

Here is what I did...

```
$("#" + rowId).find('td').eq('3').html('newText')
```

here `3` is used because I want to change my 3rd column.

Hope this is useful for someone in future :)

Comment: It is working, Only when one grid available on page scope. when page will have multiple grids then this will fail.

Comment: For multiple grids just change to: 
$("#my-jqgrid-table #" + rowId).find('td').eq('3').html('newText')

Comment: This is really not a safe solution.

Comment: This is not correct answer.. Answer given by tpeczek should be marked as correct answere

Comment: Yeah, this is bad also because you modify the DOM but you do not modify the data behind the grid (i.e. the grid[0].p.data) therefore, if you call 'reloadGrid' it will clobber the change.

Comment: Done @MarkCarpenterJr. Wow, my answer was scary.