# jqGrid - subgrid: need to use value from main grid row as subgrid column header...how?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

Is there a "simple/elegant" way to set one of the column headers (all others can be constant) of a jqGrid subgrid based on a value of one of the cells from the row it's detailing from the main grid?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is an event you can hook into when the subgrid gets displayed, but it appears it's possible to change the column label with the following:

```
jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid('setLabel', 0, 'NewLabel');
```

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4448454/109456

Comment: I'm really looking for a way to do this at the creation if at all possible.